# What would be the recurrence relation for this binary search function?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

I'm looking at this multiple choice question:

> Write the recurrence relation for the following function.
>
> ```py
> def b(arr, target, low, high):
>     if low > high:
>         return -1
>     mid = (low + high) // 2
>     if arr[mid] == target:
>         return mid
>     elif arr[mid] > target:
>         return b(arr, target, low, mid - 1)
>     else:
>         return b(arr, target, mid + 1, high)
> ```
>
> ⵔ   () = 2(/2) + O(1)
> ⵔ   () = (/2) + O(1)
> ⵔ   () = 2(−1) + O(1)
> ⵔ   () = 2(/2) + O()
> ⵔ   () = 4(/4) + O(1)
> ⦿   None of these

I think the answer is  "none of these". I'm thinking that because you're performing binary search using indexing, the array doesn't get halved or altered in any way, so technically the problem size remains the same each time the function is called.

Any input would be appreciated please.

Comment: the next recursion passes `mid` as either `low` or `high`. Does that not remove half the remaining items to check?

Comment: One is only considering values from `low..high`. The other values in the array are never used.

Comment: Please consider [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). This would be more accessible as text.

Answer (score 1):

> ...the array doesn't get halved or altered in any way, so technically the problem size remains the same each time the function is called.

This is not true: although the whole array is *available* at every call, the implemented logic will only access values in the range `low`-`high`, and so the problem size really is `high-low+1`.

Consequently, there is one option that is correct.

> T() = T(/2) + O(1)

Comment: To be fair, without stating something like "where n = high-low+1", I do think that option isn't a proper answer. That is, if the exercise asked for a recurrence relation without showing options, and a student just wrote that one without defining their n, I'd deduct a point. And I like @velzzz's thinking and might give a point for picking "none of these" annotated with their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about what `n` is. It's *not* the size of the array. It's the size of the *interval* defined by `low` and `high`, in which case `n = high - low - 1`.

Each call operates on a particular interval, which is used to focus on a particular subarray of `arr`. A recursive call is always made using a pair `(low', high')`, where one of the following is guaranteed:

1. `low < low'`
2. `high' < high`

As long as that is true, the implied value `n' = high' - low' + 1 < n` guarantees that the recursion will eventually reach the base case of `n <= 0`, checked in code by `low > high` (which is equivalent to `low - high > 0`, or `high - low < 0 == high - low + 1 <= 0`.

So `T(n)` is not, technically, the time it takes to solve a problem with `len(arr) == n`, but with `high - low + 1 == n`. The definition of `mid` and its use to define `low'` or `high'` ensures that `n` is halved for each problem.